# How to create an .exe file with Launch4j and Maven

Tags: java, maven, launch4j

I'm trying to create the .exe version of a project but I keep getting an error. I have minimal experience with Maven and I've never tried this. I've alredy created the .jar file and that's 100% working.

Here is my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.project1616</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project16x16</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <name>Project16x16</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo</id>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>DM</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>gicentreUtils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.base</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.controls</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.fxml</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.graphics</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.media</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.swing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>local</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.web</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>org.project16x16.sidescroller.SideScroller</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>none</phase>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>l4j-clui</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>launch4j</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <headerType>gui</headerType>
                                <jar>target/Project16x16-1.0.0.jar.jar</jar>
                                <outfile>target/Project16x16.exe</outfile>
                                <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                                <classPath>
                                    <mainClass>org.project16x16.sidescroller.SideScroller</mainClass>
                                    <preCp>anything</preCp>
                                </classPath>
                                <jre>
                                    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                                    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                                    <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
                                    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                                    <runtimeBits>32</runtimeBits>
                                </jre>
                                <versionInfo>
                                    <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                                    <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                                    <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                                    <copyright>2017 spiraluplabs.com</copyright>
                                    <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
                                    <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
                                    <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                                    <companyName>SpiralUp</companyName>
                                    <internalName>SpiralShareAutoAllocation</internalName>
                                    <originalFilename>SpiralShareAutoAllocation.exe</originalFilename>
                                </versionInfo>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
[INFO] Building Project16x16 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.processing:core:jar:3.3.6 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO]
[INFO] --- launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7.25:launch4j (default-cli) @ Project16x16 ---
[INFO] Platform-specific work directory already exists: C:\Users\aless\.m2\repository\net\sf\launch4j\launch4j\3.12\launch4j-3.12-workdir-win32

net.sf.launch4j.BuilderException: Enter: Header type 
    at net.sf.launch4j.Builder.build (Builder.java:76)
    at com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j.Launch4jMojo.doExecute (Launch4jMojo.java:432)
    at com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j.Launch4jMojo.execute (Launch4jMojo.java:321)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.706 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-07T16:58:38+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:1.7.25:launch4j (default-cli) on project Project16x16: Failed to build the executable; please ver
ify your configuration.: Enter: Header type -> [Help 1]
```

The command I'm using is the following:
`mvn com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j:launch4j-maven-plugin:launch4j`

I've searched for the error I'm getting but I cannot figure out a solution to this. 
Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

**EDIT**

If i run `mvn clean package` I get the following log:

```
[INFO] --------------------< org.project1616:Project16x16 >--------------------
[INFO] Building Project16x16 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ Project16x16 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\aless\Documents\Università\Secondo anno\Programmazione orientata agli oggetti\Project16x16\source\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ Project16x16 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 57 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Project16x16 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 49 source files to C:\Users\aless\Documents\Università\Secondo anno\Programmazione orientata agli oggetti\Project16x16\source\target\classes
[WARNING] /C:/Users/aless/Documents/Università/Secondo anno/Programmazione orientata agli oggetti/Project16x16/source/src/main/java/org/project16x16/sidescroller/SideScroller.java: Some
input files use or override a deprecated API.
[WARNING] /C:/Users/aless/Documents/Università/Secondo anno/Programmazione orientata agli oggetti/Project16x16/source/src/main/java/org/project16x16/sidescroller/SideScroller.java: Recom
pile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ Project16x16 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\aless\Documents\Università\Secondo anno\Programmazione orientata agli oggetti\Project16x16\source\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Project16x16 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\aless\Documents\Università\Secondo anno\Programmazione orientata agli oggetti\Project16x16\source\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ Project16x16 ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ Project16x16 ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\aless\Documents\Università\Secondo anno\Programmazione orientata agli oggetti\Project16x16\source\target\Project16x16-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.716 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-08T10:34:39+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The launch4j plugin is not even used! I updated the `pom.xml` too.

Comment: Use the command mvn clean package and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the launch4j plugin portion for the JRE detail. Find below the code and run using the command `mvn clean package`.

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>l4j-clui</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>launch4j</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <headerType>gui</headerType>
                <jar>target/Project16x16-1.0.0.jar.jar</jar>
                <outfile>target/Project16x16.exe</outfile>
                <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                <classPath>
                  <mainClass>org.project16x16.sidescroller.SideScroller</mainClass>
                  <preCp>anything</preCp>
                </classPath>
                <jre>
                    <bundledJre64Bit>false</bundledJre64Bit>
                    <bundledJreAsFallback>false</bundledJreAsFallback>
                    <minVersion>1.8.0</minVersion>
                    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
                    <runtimeBits>32</runtimeBits>
                </jre>
                <versionInfo>
                  <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                  <txtFileVersion>${project.version}</txtFileVersion>
                  <fileDescription>${project.name}</fileDescription>
                  <copyright>2017 spiraluplabs.com</copyright>
                  <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
                  <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
                  <productName>${project.name}</productName>
                  <companyName>SpiralUp</companyName>
                  <internalName>SpiralShareAutoAllocation</internalName>
                  <originalFilename>SpiralShareAutoAllocation.exe</originalFilename>
                </versionInfo>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: It didn't generate any error but it didn't create an .exe either

Comment: Remove all the maven plugins except launch4j plugin and try to check.

Comment: If possible, do you have code in GitHub so that I can check.

Comment: Here is my repo:
https://github.com/AlessandroZanatta/Project-16x16

Comment: I've found out that even if I unbind maven-jar-plugin in my `pom.xml` file, the plugin still works and the launch4j one never gets executed.

Comment: Let me check it, I have already used launch4j in some of my project.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm wasting a lot of your time.
Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I am getting compilation error in Camera.java file.

Comment: You can also directly download the project and try to build using the command mvn clean package.

Comment: Could you post the error, please? I can compile&run the code without a problem..

Comment: [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/debad/Downloads/Project-16x16-master/source/src/main/java/org/project16x16/sidescroller/Camera.java:[6,23] cannot access processing.core.PApplet
  bad class file: E:\devsoftwares\repo\local\core\1.0\core-1.0.jar(processing/core/PApplet.class)
    class file has wrong version 56.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

Comment: I am using Java 1.8, are you using a different one ?

Comment: I have edited the `pom.xml` file in the post. In this I've disabled all default plugins and binded launch4j to package phase. Although, maven-jar-plugin is used instead of launch4j. Any clue?

Comment: Yes, I'm using jdk-12.0.2. It is required for this project

Comment: If possible and if you are not using any specific JDK 12 features, can you build the project using jdk 1.8

Comment: You can't, the PApplet class was compiled with version 12 and won't allow to run with 1.8 (I hope this makes sense, I'm not that much into this kind of things).